# Is a degree in game development really more beneficial than one from computer science?

Tags: education

I need help in deciding what major to choose (I will graduate high school in a year). I have little to no experience in programming, but I'll use my spare time to learn it. 
I narrowed down my options to 3 majors, Comp Science, Game dev and cyber security. 
I've always enjoyed games and have been curious of how I could make one, but I'm quite worried about the job potential in the  country I'm living in, where the large game companies are not here yet.

If I take majors like cyber security or comp science, will I still be able to work in game development?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally don't provide career advise.

Comment: This is not really on topic and will probably be closed. But you should take a look at game developer sites, check their job openings and see what kind of qualifications are being asked for.

Comment: I've worked with colleagues with degrees in all kinds of fields, or none at all. My own degree is in Industrial Design, and now I design game systems. Another colleague studied Physics  A standard Computer Science degree is very common among game programmers. Game-specific programs are relatively new, and often focused more on game design, or jack-of-all-trades indie dev with a tiny sampling of programming, 3D art, sound, etc... So look at what the program offers and ask if those are the skills you need to do the job you want.